# Apply macro to any sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that works. I need to change the sheet name every time I run it.

I want to apply this macro to any sheet, without considering the sheetname.

```vb
Sub DeleteColumns()

Dim ColAry, i As Long, fc As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ColAry = Array("TIENDA_ID", "QCT_NAME", "PRODUCTO_ID", "CATEGORIA", _
  "FACT_NAME", "FACT_VALUE", "PRECIO HISTORICO", "CORRECIÓN", _
  "W12", "W11", "W10", "W09", _
  "W08", "W07", "W06", "W05", _
  "W04", "W03", "W02", "W01", _
  "W52", "W50", "W13", "W14", _
  "W15", "W16", "CDAR ID", "QCT")

With Sheets("Sheet11")
    For i = LBound(ColAry) To UBound(ColAry)
        fc = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        fc = Application.Match(ColAry(i), .Rows(1), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If fc > 0 Then
          .Columns(fc).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thank you for help me. I have an issue. When I made that changes and run the code, a pop-up windows ask me to create a macro. I named it and click in run again, but nothing happens after that. The columns are there.

Comment: @chrisneilsen additional, this doesn't happen with the previous code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Delete Columns With Specified Headers

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteColumnsTEST()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet11")
    
    DeleteColumns ws
    
End Sub

Sub DeleteColumns(ByVal ws As Worksheet)

    Dim ColAry As Variant: ColAry = Array( _
        "TIENDA_ID", "QCT_NAME", "PRODUCTO_ID", "CATEGORIA", _
        "FACT_NAME", "FACT_VALUE", "PRECIO HISTORICO", "CORRECIÓN", _
        "W12", "W11", "W10", "W09", _
        "W08", "W07", "W06", "W05", _
        "W04", "W03", "W02", "W01", _
        "W52", "W50", "W13", "W14", _
        "W15", "W16", "CDAR ID", "QCT")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim fc As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    With ws
        For i = LBound(ColAry) To UBound(ColAry)
            fc = Application.Match(ColAry(i), .Rows(1), 0)
            If IsNumeric(fc) Then .Columns(fc).Delete
        Next i
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```